# PostgreSQL 9.5 query performance depends on JOINed column in SELECT clause

Tags: postgresql, optimization, index-tuning

**Data:**

Over the following two tables:

```
                                      Table "public.response_logs"
  Column  |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                  Default
----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 id       | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('response_logs_id_seq'::regclass)
 status   | bigint                   |           |          |
 uuid     | text                     |           |          |
 payload  | text                     |           |          |
 accessed | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
Indexes:
    "response_logs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "response_logs_uuid_idx" UNIQUE, btree (uuid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "response_logs_uuid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uuid) REFERENCES request_logs(uuid)
```

And:

```
                                        Table "public.request_logs"
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                 Default
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------------
 id            | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('access_logs_id_seq'::regclass)
 accountid     | bigint                   |           |          |
 userid        | bigint                   |           |          |
 applicationid | bigint                   |           |          |
 requesturi    | text                     |           |          |
 method        | text                     |           |          |
 accessed      | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
 uuid          | text                     |           | not null |
 payload       | text                     |           | not null | ''::text
 apikeyid      | bigint                   |           |          |
 header        | jsonb                    |           | not null | '[]'::jsonb
Indexes:
    "request_logs_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uuid)
    "request_logs_application_idx" btree (applicationid)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "response_logs" CONSTRAINT "response_logs_uuid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (uuid) REFERENCES request_logs(uuid)
```

I'm performing the following query:

```
SELECT
  req.uuid,
  res.status,
  req.method,
  req.requesturi,
  req.accessed,
  req.payload reqpayload,
  res.payload respayload,         /* #1 - response payload */
  COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows   /* #2 - total count of response on each row in response */
FROM
  request_logs req
  INNER JOIN response_logs res ON req.uuid = res.uuid AND res.status IS NOT NULL
WHERE
   req.applicationid = 1 AND
   req.accessed BETWEEN '2018-01-01 15:04:05 +0000' AND '2019-01-02 15:04:05+0000' AND
   req.requesturi NOT ILIKE '/v1/sessions%'
ORDER BY
   accessed DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

Which takes 270 ms on average.

---

**The issue:**

I can make the query much faster by omitting `#2` (`COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows`) for rather obvious reasons. It would go to about 40 ms.

However, ***and this I find very confusing***, the query goes to about 34 ms if I omit `respayload` from the response.

---

**Questions!**

1. Shouldn't the bottle neck in any way be `COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows`? How can the query go to 40 ms with this still being calculated?
2. Why does omitting the `respayload` give such an improvement? Removing `reqpayload` doesn't have a similar effect and it's even if we don't add `respayload`, we still need to grab the `response_log` with corresponding UUID to copy the `status` into the response.
3. Considering that the only changing query values are the `applicationid` and the date we compared `accessed` with, which further improvements including indexing can be done to help performance?

---

**Further data!**

Here is `explain analyse` for the different query configurations:

With `respayload` and `COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows`:

```
Limit  (cost=2826.59..2829.09 rows=1000 width=823) (actual time=408.535..419.136 rows=1000 loops=1)
      ->  Sort  (cost=2826.59..2829.79 rows=1281 width=823) (actual time=408.524..412.154 rows=1000 loops=1)
            Sort Key: req.accessed DESC
            Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 2064kB
            ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1090.16..2760.47 rows=1281 width=823) (actual time=368.207..390.866 rows=3951 loops=1)
                  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1090.16..2744.46 rows=1281 width=823) (actual time=50.244..127.325 rows=3951 loops=1)
                        Hash Cond: (res.uuid = req.uuid)
                        ->  Seq Scan on response_logs res  (cost=0.00..1607.26 rows=9126 width=758) (actual time=0.008..36.196 rows=9129 loops=1)
                              Filter: (status IS NOT NULL)
                        ->  Hash  (cost=1044.85..1044.85 rows=3625 width=102) (actual time=38.739..38.739 rows=4046 loops=1)
                              Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1122kB
                              ->  Index Scan using request_logs_application_idx on request_logs req  (cost=0.29..1044.85 rows=3625 width=102) (actual time=0.035..22.009 rows=4046 loops=1)
                                    Index Cond: (applicationid = 1)
                                    Filter: ((accessed >= '2018-01-01 15:04:05+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (accessed <= '2019-01-02 15:04:05+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (requesturi !~~* '/v1/sessions%'::text))
    Planning time: 2.699 ms
    Execution time: 423.068 ms
```

With `respayload` and without `COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows`:

```
Limit  (cost=2810.58..2813.08 rows=1000 width=823) (actual time=136.977..146.820 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2810.58..2813.78 rows=1281 width=823) (actual time=136.967..140.334 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: req.accessed DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 2064kB
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1090.16..2744.46 rows=1281 width=823) (actual time=47.127..119.808 rows=3951 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (res.uuid = req.uuid)
              ->  Seq Scan on response_logs res  (cost=0.00..1607.26 rows=9126 width=758) (actual time=0.015..33.307 rows=9129 loops=1)
                    Filter: (status IS NOT NULL)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1044.85..1044.85 rows=3625 width=102) (actual time=38.328..38.328 rows=4046 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1122kB
                    ->  Index Scan using request_logs_application_idx on request_logs req  (cost=0.29..1044.85 rows=3625 width=102) (actual time=0.047..21.813 rows=4046 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (applicationid = 1)
                          Filter: ((accessed >= '2018-01-01 15:04:05+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (accessed <= '2019-01-02 15:04:05+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (requesturi !~~* '/v1/sessions%'::text))
Planning time: 3.882 ms
Execution time: 150.465 ms
```

Without `respayload` and with `COUNT(*) OVER() AS total_rows`:

```
Limit  (cost=2826.59..2829.09 rows=1000 width=110) (actual time=164.428..174.760 rows=1000 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=2826.59..2829.79 rows=1281 width=110) (actual time=164.418..167.956 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: req.accessed DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 564kB
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1090.16..2760.47 rows=1281 width=110) (actual time=133.997..148.382 rows=3951 loops=1)
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1090.16..2744.46 rows=1281 width=110) (actual time=46.282..119.070 rows=3951 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (res.uuid = req.uuid)
                    ->  Seq Scan on response_logs res  (cost=0.00..1607.26 rows=9126 width=45) (actual time=0.009..33.656 rows=9129 loops=1)
                          Filter: (status IS NOT NULL)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1044.85..1044.85 rows=3625 width=102) (actual time=37.844..37.844 rows=4046 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1122kB
                          ->  Index Scan using request_logs_application_idx on request_logs req  (cost=0.29..1044.85 rows=3625 width=102) (actual time=0.029..21.602 rows=4046 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (applicationid = 1)
                                Filter: ((accessed >= '2018-01-01 15:04:05+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (accessed <= '2019-01-02 15:04:05+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (requesturi !~~* '/v1/sessions%'::text))
Planning time: 3.758 ms
Execution time: 178.675 ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying various configuration, I think I found the answer to my own question. It's not 100% proven but it makes sense.

The `COUNT(*) OVER() as total_rows` command executes the entire query, including the `WHERE` clause **AND** the `SELECT` fields. So when the result set is very big, much larger than the `LIMIT 1000`, we would still be copying all the matching records according to the columns indicated in `SELECT`, including the `respayload`.

Since `respayload` can be fairly big, when the unlimited response count is high, let's say 10K, then 10K `respayload`s are copied, only to later be discarded, as the copy of the selected columns happens again for only the first 1000 (because of limit) records.

That's why omitting `respayload` from the statement improved performance so drastically.

I will be careful in the future where I use `COUNT(*) OVER()` as this seems to be seriously affected by the selected columns.